# How do i get the ComboBox items text of each item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor I did:

```
ComboboxItem item1 = new ComboboxItem();
item1.Text = "Processor";
item1.Value = "Win32_Processor";
ComboboxItem item2 = new ComboboxItem();
item2.Text = "DiskDrive";
item2.Value = "Win32_DiskDrive";
cmbxOption.Items.Add(item1);
cmbxOption.Items.Add(item2);

ComboboxItem[] items = new ComboboxItem[cmbxOption.Items.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = new ComboboxItem();
    items[i].Text = cmbxOption.GetItemText(i);
}
```

But instead doing a new instance for each item and add the item to the `cmbxOption` I want to make a for loop that will add all the items from the `cmbxOption` to the `ComboboxItem[]`.

In the form1 designer in the ComboBox in the property items I already have the items in the Collection:

```
Win32_1394Controller
Win32_1394ControllerDevice
Win32_BaseBoard
Win32_Battery
Win32_BIOS
Win32_Bus
Win32_CDROMDrive
Win32_CIMLogicalDeviceCIMDataFile
Win32_DeviceBus
Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress
Win32_DeviceSettings
Win32_DisplayConfiguration
Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration
Win32_DMAChannel
Win32_DriverVXD
Win32_FloppyController
Win32_FloppyDrive
Win32_HeatPipe
Win32_IDEController
Win32_IDEControllerDevice
Win32_InfraredDevice
Win32_IRQResource
Win32_Keyboard
Win32_MotherboardDevice
Win32_OnBoardDevice
Win32_PCMCIAController
Win32_PNPAllocatedResource
Win32_PnPDevice
Win32_PnPEntity
Win32_PointingDevice
Win32_PortableBattery
Win32_PortConnector
Win32_PortResource
Win32_POTSModem
Win32_POTSModemToSerialPort
Win32_PowerManagementEvent
Win32_Printer
Win32_PrinterConfiguration
Win32_PrinterController
Win32_PrinterDriverDll
Win32_PrinterSetting
Win32_PrinterShare
Win32_PrintJob
Win32_Processor
Win32_SCSIController
Win32_SCSIControllerDevice
Win32_SerialPort
Win32_SerialPortConfiguration
Win32_SerialPortSetting
Win32_SMBIOSMemory
Win32_SoundDevice
Win32_TemperatureProbe
Win32_USBController
Win32_USBControllerDevice
Win32_VideoConfiguration
Win32_VideoController
Win32_VideoSettings
Win32_VoltageProbe
```

I want to take each item and create for it `ComboboxItem` Text and Value. Just not to do it manual.

This is a class i did:

```
public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }
```

And then later this is how i use it when select the item:

```
private void cmbxOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo((cmbxOption.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString(), ref lstDisplayHardware, chkHardware.Checked);
        }
```

It does working when i'm doing it manual in the constructor adding each time a new item to the cmbxOption Text and Value but instead adding each item manual i want to use the items i already have in the cmbxOption.

Comment: How do you plan to obtain the Value when there is only Text in the ComboBox items? And what's wrong with the existing code?

Comment: IllidanS4 i didn't add yet the line of the Value inside the loop. I just tested the  Text first.  The problem in this code is that i'm getting as Text the number 0 instead getting the cmbxOption.GetItemText(i) Text what i get is 0 since i = 0 first time. But what i want to get is the Item Text/Name for example the first item text/name is Win32_1394Controller but i'm getting 0.

Comment: IllidanS4 i added the missing code i forgot to add the class i'm using and the selectedindexchanged event and explained what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetItemText` just returns a textual representation of an object, not the text of an item on the index. Try this:

```
using System.Linq;

ComboboxItem[] items = cmbxOption.Items.Cast<string>().Select(s => new ComboboxItem{Value = s, Text = s.Substring(6)}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm getting exception on this line invalidcastexception: Unable to cast object of type 'ComboboxItem' to type 'System.String'

Comment: @Barbari I thought the combobox is full of strings (you said you made it in the designer). Which types of objects does the combobox contain?

Comment: The combobox in the designer it's collection of items does full of items already and they are strings. When i click in the designer on the Collection of the items property i see inside many strings like i show in my question all the Win32....and it say: Enter the strings in the collection (one per line).

Comment: @Barbari The exception means you have a ComboboxItem there. First use the first code, before adding anything other to the combobox, then add all `items` back.

Comment: IllidanS4 it's working now i see in the list items in item in the Value i see the name for example in the first item in the list i see in Value "Win32_1394Controller" what i did is this: ComboboxItem[] items2 = cmbxOption.Items.Cast<string>().Select(s => new ComboboxItem { Value = s }).ToArray(); instead Text i changed it to Value. Now i need to create a new list of items but this time with Text and this time only the name i mean the list now should contain in each item only the name without the Win32_ for example "1394Controller"  without the Win32_ how can i create this Text list ?

Comment: @Barbari Are you sure? Don't you want to have only one list of ComoboxItems with both Value and Text?

Comment: This is working creating the Text list: ComboboxItem[] items3 = cmbxOption.Items.Cast<string>().Select(s => new ComboboxItem
            {
                Text = s.Substring(6)
            }).ToArray();

Comment: IllidanS4 you right it's working but you right it's better to have one list with both Text and Value. How do i do it ? I can make now the two lists it's working without exceptions but now i need to make it one list.

Comment: Ok now i did the loop and changed it inside i did: for (int i = 0; i < items1.Length; i++)
            {
                cmbxOption.Items.Add(items1[i].Text);
            }

Comment: The problem is with the line in the cmbxoption_SelectedIndexChanged event: InsertInfo((cmbxOption.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString(), ref lstDisplayHardware, chkHardware.Checked); i'm getting null when selecting item why ?

Comment: @Barbari Add the items like this: `foreach(var item in items1) cmbxOption.Items.Add(item);` You don't have to add Text, because the object has ToString. Also mark the code in comments with backtick: `.

Comment: Using foreach like you did make it work but also adding to the cmbxoption the Win32_...list. And i wanted only the Text.

Comment: The idea is to have in Combobox(cmxoption) only the Text of each item for example Processor and not Win32_Processor and then when i select the Processor it should act in the in SelectedIndexChanged event as Win32_Processor

Comment: @Barbari It can't add Win32_ items. ComboBox formats its objects based on their ToString. ComboboxItem ToString returns Text, so the display name should stay the same.

Comment: IllidanS4 Ah right the problem is that i have in the designer already the items in the ocmbobox as Win32_....thats why i see them too. But i also need them since i use them with the ComboboxItem[] so maybe i can remove them after doing the loop somehow ?